# Maximal symplectic subspace of a presymplectic vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a presymplectic vector space, that is $V$ is a vector space and $\omega:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is skew-symmetric.

We say that $W \subset V$ is a symplectic subspace if $\omega$ is non degenerate on $W$

> Must a maximal symplectic subspace be unique?

Comment: No. It is any complement of the kernel of $\omega$, and there are infinitely many such complements (unless $\omega$ is symplectic)

Comment: when you say any complement of the kernel, what do you mean by this? I interpret compliment of the kernel of $\omega$ to mean $V/\ker(\omega)$, but this is obviously unqiue.

Comment: By a complement I mean a subspace of $V$ such that ...

Comment: We take $U$ a subspace of $V$ and then take he compliment of the kernel in $U$?

Comment: Choose a basis $u_1,\dots,u_n$ in the kernel of $\omega$, then extend it arbitrarily by $v_1,\dots,v_k$ to a basis of $V$. Now ${\rm span}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is a complement of $\ker\omega$, but the basis extension was arbitrary, far from being unique, e.g. $v_1+u_1,\,v_2+u_1,\,\dots,\,v_k+u_1$ would work just as well..